# Проблемы с событиями в tkinter(python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть вот такой код

```
from tkinter import *
from re_text import *

root=Tk()

def func(event):
    print("123")
    def fi(event):
        top_read(root,l['text'],l)
    l=Label(root, text="hello")
    l.bind("<Button-1>", fi)
    l.pack()
_list=Listbox(root)
_list.insert(END, "test element")
_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", func)
_list.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

модуль re_text:

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Text, FLAT, Tk, END
from tkinter.ttk import Button

class top_read(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, text, widget):
        self.text = text
        self.widget = widget
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title("Редактировать строку")
        self.gui()
    def gui(self):
        self.geometry("680x300")
        self.ob = Text(self, relief=FLAT, height=17, width=72)
        self.ob.insert('end',self.text)
        self.b = Button(self, text="Сохранить", command=self._command_for_button)
        self.b.place(x=600,y=261)
        self.ob.place(x=15,y=9)
    def _command_for_button(self):
        self.widget['text'] = self.ob.get(1.0,END)[:-1]
        self.destroy()
```

Проблема:

Когда после нажатия на label с текстом hello, как и задумано появляется окно редактирования. Если выделить текст в этом окне, то каким то магическим образом(или нет) запускается функция func. А если допустим заменить ListboxSelect на Button-1 то не какой "магии" не наблюдается.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при выделении одного  элемента  `ListboxSelect` выполнялось функция `func` и пока это выделение не было прекращено эта функция повторялась повторно 2й раз. Для того чтобы все исправить используйте сигнал `<ButtonRelease-1>` или `<Button-1>`.

Пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Button


class TopRead(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, text, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text
        self.widget = widget

        self.title("Редактировать строку")
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.geometry("680x300")
        self.ob = Text(self, relief=FLAT, height=17, width=72)
        self.ob.insert('end', self.text)
        self.b = Button(self, text="Сохранить", command=self._command_for_button)
        self.b.place(x=600,y=261)
        self.ob.place(x=15,y=9)

    def _command_for_button(self):
        self.widget['text'] = self.ob.get(1.0, END)[:-1]
        self.destroy()

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        _list = Listbox(self)
        _list.insert(END, "test element")
        _list.pack()
        _list.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.func)

    def func(self, event):
        print("123")
        self.l = Label(self, text="hello")
        self.l.bind("<Button-1>", self.fi)
        self.l.pack()

    def fi(self, event):
            self.text = self.l['text']
            self.g = TopRead(self.text, self.l)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста объяснить поподробней, почему func два раза вызывается. И почему именно при выделении текста?

Comment: @Gleb вот смотрите что делают сами сигналы `ListboxSelect` значит при выделении объекта в `Listbox`  выполняется функция `func`, а при использовании сигнала `Button-1` или `ButtonRelease-1` функция выполняется когда на вы нажимаете ЛКМ на сам объект в `Listbox`. По этому при выделении другого объекта выполняется функция `func` т.к. у вас до этого был выделен объект в `listbox`. Так что сама "Магия"  происходит тупо из-за обработки сигнала

Comment: Вы же заметили что повторно она не повторяется если заново нажать на `label` после такой проблемы, а если заново нажать на объект в `listbox` то такая проблема опять повторяется.